# JavaFX 11 Setup without manually edit build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, java-11

I Want to create a gradle Project for JavaFX11.

I already can create and run a Java FX11 Project by using Build Paths and VM Arguments. This was only a workaround because Gradle could not compile JavaFX, because of a Runtime Version error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Eclipse Version : 2019-03

Gradle version : 5.2.1

OS :

```
Distributor ID:         Ubuntu
Description:            Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:                18.04
```

I already Fixed everything that could be the Cause: 
Eclipse setup :

Compiler Complience level -> 11
Installed JRE : jdk-11.0.2

Ubuntu Java Setup :

```
java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Gradle :

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9-LTS)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-47-generic amd64
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {

    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}
def currentOS = org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current()
def platform
if (currentOS.isWindows()) {
    platform = 'win'
} else if (currentOS.isLinux()) {
    platform = 'linux'
} else if (currentOS.isMacOsX()) {
     platform = 'mac'
}



dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}



repositories {

    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    moduless = ['javafx.controls','javafx.fxml']
    version ='11.0.2'

}

mainClassName = 'de.dom.main.MainApp'
```

**EDIT GRADLE WRAPPER**

gradle.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.3.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2
```

**EDIT FOR PROMLEM FIX**

create *in the root of the project* a gradle.properties that contains :

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2
```

Comment: I don't know whether it matters but your output says you are using Gradle 5.2.1 and not 5.3.1

Comment: @mipa sorry my fault. I have gradle 5.2.1 . But this is not the problem, i think. I need to configure Gradle, so it uses the Java 11 runtime enfiroment (class version 55) and i tried everyting to configure the jre. 
it even runs. But only the Gradle integration wont work with java fx.

Comment: Have you checked https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse? The section for Gradle has some hints...

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes I configured my Buildpath manualy, wich worked. But I can't build a JavaFX Project with gradle.

Comment: Have you set `org.gradle.java.home` pointing to JDK 11?

Comment: @JoséPereda
I configured the gradle Properties file already. I updated My Post

Comment: That is not the gradle properties file, that is the `gradle-wrapper` one. You need to create a `gradle.properties` with that property, and add it to the root of the project.

Comment: @JoséPereda  
That worked for me. thank you!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create gradle.properties